# Unable to read memory when accessing file using fstream

Tags: c++

I know this question as been asked before, but it was never answered and my situation is different

I am creating a student struct to store student information:

```cpp
struct Student {
  std::string m_firstname = "";
  std::string m_lastname = "";
  int m_testscore = {0};
  char m_grade;
};
```

I want to read the student name from a text file into an array, I have a function for that:

```cpp
// Read student data into an array
Student read_data() {
    Student students[20];

    // Open input file
    std::ifstream input("name.txt", std::ios::in);

    // Check if file is good
    if (!input) {
      std::cout << "Error occurred" << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    }

    // Read data from file
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      input >> students[i].m_firstname >> students[i].m_lastname;
    }

    // Display data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      std::cout << students[i].m_firstname << " " << students[i].m_lastname << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```

When I run the program, everything works and I get all the student information from the file displayed in a console, but then I also get an error ***"Unable to read memory" and "Access violation"***, I set a break point and after stepping through the code I found out that the error occurs when I am accessing the file stream, here is what the debugger says

```
std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >    <Unable to read memory>
```

Text file:

```
Guillermo Mora
Hugh Hanna
Isaac Atkinson
Teodoro Macdonald
Esperanza Sawyer
Werner Daugherty
Fran Middleton
Alvin Rowland
Richie Patterson
Mario Simpson
Lewis Wolf
Maria Yates
Ernest Cuevas
Andrea Bernard
Nigel Carlson
Dennis Owen
Ezra Jacobs
Sarah Francis
Jarvis Peterson
Erika Harmon
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates the error. This includes the input file. The only thing I see is that your function does not return any students even though it promised to do so. So, if you happen to be printing the return value, it has good chance to crash.

Comment: Your function doesn't return a value despite being defined as doing so, which could be causing the errors you see. Please fix that first.

Comment: @Quimby thank you, your suggestion is exactly what happened. Brain farts I tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because I was promising to return a type that was never returned with the read_data() function. it should be:

```cpp
void read_data() {
    Student students[20];

    // Open input file
    std::ifstream input("name.txt", std::ios::in);

    // Check if file is good
    if (!input) {
      std::cout << "Error occurred" << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    }

    // Read data from file
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      input >> students[i].m_firstname >> students[i].m_lastname;
    }

    // Display data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      std::cout << students[i].m_firstname << " " << students[i].m_lastname << std::endl;
    }
    input.close();
}
```